# sharepoint 2013 links open in new tab always checked

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am facing an issue in which all the links (that I inserted using Insert-->Links option for the list items ) have their 'open in new tab' always checked .This issue occurs only for those list items that I migrated from sharepoint 2010 to 2013.Even though I uncheck it and save it in database (in database it is saved with uncheck value) ,whenever I edit the List item ,all its links have this value checked .I am not understanding exactly where this has been done.
['open in new tab' checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTncZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the "Launch forms in a dialog box?" in List parameters

[image: Open in Dialog]